# List service charges in checkout page

Tags: square-connect, square, square-checkout

I'm using the square checkout API to generate a checkout URL and I want to include fees like "shipping & handling". Doing this using the "service_charges" field adds the charge to the total, but it doesn't list the charge.

Here is what my service_charges field looks like:

```js
"service_charges": [
          {
            "amount_money": {
              "amount": 100,
              "currency": "USD"
            },
            "calculation_phase": "SUBTOTAL_PHASE",
            "name": "Shipping & Handling",
            "taxable": false,
            "uid": "shipping"
          }
        ]
```

The generated checkout page looks like this:

[Checkout Page Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsMMl.png)

Is there any way to get service charges listed so expenses aren't added without showing in the price breakdown?

If not, what are best practices for including the shipping fee using the checkout API?

Thanks.